# Add/Remove Kestrel Grpc services during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, kestrel

Question: Is it possible to register/deregister grpc services after the startup?

Following is the traditional way of registering grpc service:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterErvice>();
        });
    }
}
```

Taken from well known sample grpc.net project. Sources e.g.: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Greeter/Server/Startup.cs or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

What is the recommended way of adding/removing services once the startup is finished and kestrel started?
One way would be to use single dummy routing service that would then holding the registry of services and routing requests to them. This however requires contracts changes plus probably reinvents the wheel of proper handler discovery and routing.